# using miktex portable INSTEAD of system wide installation with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, portability, miktex

I would like to create an USB-Stick you can put into any windows with **VSCode**, **miktex** (and perl) **portable** to work on my thesis with any win device.

VSCode and perl are working just fine and miktex portable also starts.

When trying to compile my thesis within VSCode though, it **tries using the miktex system wide installation**, which does not necessarily work (at university, the PC always fails with "User/Administrator-updates are not synchron" and I do not have the admin rights to correct that).

I **tried**

1. deleting miktech from the PATH before adding the portable path (does work, checked) as
   well as
2. modifying the settings in VSCode by adding "env" to the Latex like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526320/how-can-i-get-vscodes-latex-workshop-to-find-the-right-installation-of-tex) (see below)

It still tries to use the system miktex installation. Except for the error, it also shows in the log, because it installs and uses the packages into/in APPDATA instead of using those in the portable folder.

###### "Code"

VSCode settings.json got the "env" entry (although I am not too sure what it does)

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [

        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-pdf",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {"TEXMFHOME": "C:\\Users\\c.hoehl\\Documents\\portableBA\\CommonFiles\\miktex\\texmfs\\install\\miktex\\bin\\x64"},
        },
```

or instead (actually tried all kind of paths)

```
"env": {"TEXMFHOME": "...\\portable\\miktex\\texmfs"},
```

Of cause, the '...' represents the full path to the folder.

---

**Does anyone have an idea, how to make it work?**

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I would love to see an answer here. I just tried something similar, because of my restrictions on my work computer. I have VSCode, Perl and MiKTeX portable on a stick, but still need to enter the Path environment variables into my user settings to get it work. It would be great to find a way to set it relatively in VSCode, so that it just runs when plugged in.